# Processing Translations

Tags: matrix, processing, translation

In the processing language I am trying to create a translation similar to the image below:
[Output Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBRP0.png)

In my code, the image is moving but it isn't showing the original picture in addition to the translation and it isn't being shown across the screen as i'd like.

I have included the code I have so far below:

```
PImage img;

int reps=10;

void setup()
{
size(600,120);
triangle(30,5,50,30,15,20);
save("image.png");
img=loadImage("image.png");
}
void draw() 
{
for (int i=0; i<reps; i++);
{
pushMatrix();
image(img,0,0);
translate(img.height,0);
scale(-1,1); 
image(img,0,0);
popMatrix();
}
}
```

This is what it produces so far:
[current_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKdDG.png)

Im happy it's translating, I am just trying to figure out how to see the original in addition to the translation and have it shown multiple times.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<reps; i++);` you should remove the semicolon here. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, could you rephrase? It's probably clear enough but english isn't my first language and I'm unsure what you're trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to make a couple copies of two mirrored triangles?

Answer (score 0):

The images have to be translated differently depending on the index. The 2nd image has to be translated more than the 1st one and the 3rd more than the 2nd:

```java
translate(img.height * i, 0);
```

function `draw`:

```
void draw() 
{
    for (int i=0; i<reps; i++);
    {
        pushMatrix();
        translate(img.height * i, 0);
        scale(-1,1); 
        image(img,0,0);
        popMatrix();
    }
}
```